# Connect to Firebird DB via ODBC in R

Tags: r, odbc

I am trying to connect to Firebird DB via ODBC. I have R Studio Server installed on a Linux virtual machine. I use dbConnect. This connection works fine on my local machine. However, on the server I get an error:

`Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [ODBC Firebird Driver]connection shutdown [ODBC Firebird Driver]Invalid connection string attribute`

Other error:
`"Error: std::bad_alloc".`

My dbconnect:

```
odbc_con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "Firebird",
                      Server = 'xxx',
                      Database = '10.1.xxx.gdb', 
                      Uid = 'xxx',
                      Pwd = 'xxx',
                      encoding = "cp1250")

> odbc::odbcListDrivers()
      name   attribute                          value
1 Firebird Description InterBase/Firebird ODBC Driver
2 Firebird      Driver          /usr/lib/libOdbcFb.so
3 Firebird       Setup         /usr/lib/libOdbcFbS.so
4 Firebird   Threading                              1
5 Firebird   FileUsage                              1
6 Firebird   CPTimeout                           <NA>
7 Firebird     CPReuse                           <NA>
```

Comment: is that list of drivers locally or on the rstudio server (i.e., local to the VM)?

Comment: I'd look at the ODBC driver versions themselves, contrasting your local with the VM; depending on the OS, you may be able to use `dpkg`, `yum`, `rpm`, or whatever package-manager the OS has.

Comment: @r2evans this is list of drivers on the rstudio server

Comment: during the first call the code works, when i want to call the code second time i see error: ```Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [ODBC Firebird Driver]connection shutdown [ODBC Firebird Driver]Invalid connection string attribute``` I have to leave the current session

Comment: You define `odbc_con` and can get successfully execute one query/statement, after which the connection is unusable? It could be a bug in the driver itself (outside of R), in `odbc` (R package), or in the code you're doing (I'm having a hard time thinking of a sequence of R expressions that would trigger that behavior, but who knows). If I'm correct, can you please add (to the question) this behavior? Perhaps as simple as `odbc_con <- dbConnect(...); dbGetQuery(odbc_con, "select 1 as a"); dbGetQuery(odbc_con, "select 2 as b")` (first succeeds, second fails)?